# Jquery Dialog Validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I'm trying to figure out why my errors messages are not showing up in the Dialog and why the Dialog doesn't close when I fill out the form and click "Send Email".  I'm sure it is something I'm missing but I don't see it.

Cliffs:  I click a link (same class since there are multiple links) on the main page to bring up a Dialog box that asks for Name, Email and Password.  Name and Email are required and the errors messages should be shown in a pretty UI Alert box.  Instead, the error messages are shown underneath the text boxes and when the form fields are filled out correctly, the Dialog box doesn't close.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
  <a href="Class1" class="Roster">View Roster</a>
  <a href="Class2" class="Roster">View Roster</a>
  <a href="Class3" class="Roster">View Roster</a>
  <a href="Class4" class="Roster">View Roster</a>
 .
 .
</html>   

$("#RosterForm").validate({
    errorContainer: "#errorblock-div1, #errorblock-div2",
    errorLabelContainer: "#errorblock-div2 ul",
    wrapper: "li",
    rules: {
        FullName: { required: true },
        Email: { required: true }
    },
    messages: {
        FullName: { required: "Please enter your name." },
        Email: { required: "Please enter your email address." }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit({
            target: '#client-script-return-data',

            success: function() { $(".dialog_form").dialog("close"); successEvents('#client-script-return-msg'); }
         });
     }
});

$(".Roster").click(function(event) { 
  event.preventDefault();
  URL = "roster.cfm?" + $(this).attr("href");
  $('<div class="dialog_form">').dialog({
    title: "Student Roster",
    width: 800,
    height: 650,
    modal: true,
    open: function ()
      {
       $(this).parent().appendTo("#RosterForm");
       $(this).load(URL);
      },
    close: function() {
        $(".dialog_form").remove();
    },
    buttons: {
              "Send Email": function() { $("#RosterForm").submit(); },
              "Cancel": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }       
             }
});

return false; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an conditional to the "Send Email" button:

```
buttons: {
    "Send Email": function() { 
        if (jQuery(#RosterForm").valid() {
            $("#RosterForm").submit(); 
        } else {
            // display errors
        }
    },
```

Comment: The code you gave didn't help any at all.  It does submit the form in the Dialog box but the Dialog box won't close.